# Framework 7 Accordion not display when i click it , i know problem is at JS file?

Tags: javascript, accordion, html-framework-7

I am using the latest V2 F7. So here is my index.html , i have exactly like this

```
<div class="block-title">Separate Collapsibles</div>
<div class="list">
<ul>
    <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-content item-link">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="block">
                <p>Item 1 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-content item-link">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="block">
                <p>Item 2 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

my customindex.js

```
var app = new Framework7();

var $ = Dom7;

$('.accordion-item').on('accordion:opened', function () {
 app.dialog.alert('Accordion item opened');
});

$('.accordion-item').on('accordion:closed', function (e) {
 app.dialog.alert('Accordion item closed');
});

app.on('accordionOpened', function (el) {
  console.log('The following element opened:');
  console.log(el);
});

   //i added this function but gives error message , cannot set property 'f7View' of undefined
   var viewMain = app.view.create('.view-main',{});
$$('.accordion-item').on('accordion:opened', function () {
  app.dialog.alert('Accordion item opened');
});
```

I do what exactly as Framework7 docs do, i got the tag `div id="app"` and `div class = "view view-main"` as well. Please i need some guidance... Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Okay , i got some mistake , problem solved by install full version of framework 7 `npm i install framework7`